# Problem in Build Gradle Version when running app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Also flutter doctor shows no error

Comment: Can you please share project level build.gradle file and  gradle-wrapper.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean the current build and try:
flutter pub get

If this does not work, then there is an issue with your android installation. It is recommended to re-install android studio with all the necessary packages.